# Adding multiple arrays to same key

Tags: php, arrays, loops

This seems like a relatively easy thing to do but I'm struggling a bit. Here is a bit of backstory. I'm currently making a schedule of events based off a web service.

Because of the way it outputs data I've been creating and rearranging the information based off the clients wants/needs.

I've created a time array that basically loops through the open hours in 15 min intervals. Example...

```
Array
(
    [0600] => 0
    [0615] => 0
    [0630] => 0
    [0645] => 0
    [0700] => 0
    [0715] => 0
    [0730] => 0
    [0745] => 0
    [0800] => 0
    [0815] => 0
    [0830] => 0
    [0845] => 0
    [0900] => 0
    ...etc etc
    [2300] => 0
)
```

Once I've done that I loop(using a *foreach*) through events and if the time is equal to a key add it to the array. The variables are just items from web service.

```
$timeArray[date('Hi', $roundStart)] = array(
    'e_name' => $eventName,
    'e_build_id' => $buildId,
    'e_start' => $timeStampS,
    'e_end' => $timeStampE,
    'e_class' => $eClass,
    'e_span' => $fullSpan,
    'e_status' => $canCheck,
    'e_lanes' => $lanesOpen
);
```

But I've noticed there is a bug with this and that if you have two events at the same time the last one will override the other one. What I need instead is for the events to be within the same key. So adding two or more arrays to the key.

Let me know if this makes sense?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: change `$timeArray[date('Hi', $roundStart)] = ` to `$timeArray[date('Hi', $roundStart)][] = ` . that way it will have array of events in each time key.

Comment: @kcroake88 Are you looking for multiple mappings for a given key? AKA one to many

Comment: You could initialize the time array values as arrays, then use `array_push()` to add the event arrays inside of the array stored for the key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your initial array, make the values empty arrays:

```
Array
(
    [0600] => []
    ...etc etc
    [2300] => []
)
```

then when you assign, just push on the array

```
$timearray[$time][] = $event;
```

just make sure you always treat the `$timearray` indexes as arrays, even if they only contain one (or zero!) events.

good luck!

Comment: That.... makes total sense. Didn't even think of that. I'll try this out.

Answer (score 0):

Just make every entry in your interval array an array

```
// instead the if condition you can initialize the array in your loop when creating it
if (!is_array($timeArray[date('Hi', $roundStart)])) {
    $timeArray[date('Hi', $roundStart)] = array();
}
$timeArray[date('Hi', $roundStart)][] = array(
    'e_name' => $eventName,
    'e_build_id' => $buildId,
    'e_start' => $timeStampS,
    'e_end' => $timeStampE,
    'e_class' => $eClass,
    'e_span' => $fullSpan,
    'e_status' => $canCheck,
    'e_lanes' => $lanesOpen
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Array
(
   [0600] => array()
```

...

and

```
$timeArray[date('Hi', $roundStart)][] = array(
   'e_name' => $eventName,
   'e_build_id' => $buildId
```

...

Answer (score 0):

So instead of setting every hour to `0`, better set everything to an empty array in your initial run. Instead of checking against `0`, you can then check against an array with 0 length. So basically the same. For your date setting loop, you will now, instead of creating a new array, just push to that array. Something like

```
array_push($timeArray[date('Hi', $roundStart)], array(
    'e_name' => $eventName,
    'e_build_id' => $buildId,
    'e_start' => $timeStampS,
    'e_end' => $timeStampE,
    'e_class' => $eClass,
    'e_span' => $fullSpan,
    'e_status' => $canCheck,
    'e_lanes' => $lanesOpen
));
```

should do the job.

After that, just loop over the dates at any given time and execute them all.